# Pass Button Name to Function

Tags: vb.net, variables, button

I'm using the below code to clear a user attribute in Active Directory when a button is clicked. I have several of these buttons (1 each for title, department, address, city, state, zip, country, phone). I could just have the same code below for each of the 8 button clicks. However, I thought it might be cleaner, and reduce the amount of code, to pass the name of each button to a single sub routine, so you only need it once, not 8 times, and then use

```
dirEntryResults.Properties("btnName").Clear()
```

However, I can't see if it's possible to pass the button name to a sub routine? Is this possible, and if so, how?

```
Private Sub ClearTitle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearTitle.Click
    Dim ADName As String = GetLogonName()
    Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
    Dim dirSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
    dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=test.account))"
    dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    Dim searchResults As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
    If Not searchResults Is Nothing Then
        Dim dirEntryResults As New DirectoryEntry(searchResults.Path)
        dirEntryResults.Properties("title").Clear()
        dirEntryResults.CommitChanges()
        dirEntryResults.Close()
        MsgBox("Attribute Cleared", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success")
    End If
    dirEntry.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at the event arguments - one of the is `sender` which is the button clicked.

Comment: sender param is the button which triggered the click event. You an type cast the sender to a button object and extract the Property value as you design and pass it on the helper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.  Note that I am guessing at the actual names of the buttons, and using only one handler for all of the clicks.

```
Private Sub Clears_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClearTitle.Click, ClearAddress.Click, ClearCity.Click 'etc

    Dim BTN_NAME As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).Name.ToLower.Replace("clear", "")

    Dim ADName As String = GetLogonName()
    Dim dirEntry As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
    Dim dirSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
    dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=test.account))"
    dirSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    Dim searchResults As SearchResult = dirSearcher.FindOne()
    If Not searchResults Is Nothing Then
        Dim dirEntryResults As New DirectoryEntry(searchResults.Path)

        dirEntryResults.Properties(BTN_NAME).Clear()

        dirEntryResults.CommitChanges()
        dirEntryResults.Close()
        MsgBox("Attribute Cleared", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success")
    End If
    dirEntry.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was getting close, I'd found another post which suggested adding `Dim btnName As String` and another said `Dim addedButton As Button = sender` but both were throwing errors about not bing able to convert button to string. It was missing the additional `DirectCast(sender, Button).Name` that you suggested.